# Mechanism of Friedel-Crafts acylation with succinic anhydride

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

[image]

Here is my proposed mechanism, something tells me that the intramolecular deprotonation happens after, and that this is not concerted. Is my mechanism correct? 
[image: My[![Friediel Crafts Acylation mechanism]

Comment: Don’t draw it concerted. It is a stepwise process; the attack of the aromatic electrons onto the electrophile first with a delocalised carbocation as intermediate followed by deprotonation and rearomatising.

Answer (score 8):

The reactivity of acid chlorides and acid anhydrides are actually quite similar. It may be helpful for you to think of an acid anhydride like this:

[image: Comparison between anhydride and acyl chloride]

When we do, the acylation reaction is almost identical to that of an acid chloride, where an acylium cation $\ce{R-C#O+}$ is generated:

[image: Acylation mechanism]

The subsequent proton exchange restores aromaticity:

[image: Proton exchange]